# Sending an xlsx file using sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This works:

```
EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients     = 'myaddress@helloworld.co.uk',  
    @subject        = 'HELLO WORLD',
    @Importance     = 'LOW',
    @body           = 'HELLO WORLD',
    @file_attachments       = N'UNCpathway\experimental attachment.txt'
```

Whereas when I try this

```
EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients     = 'myaddress@helloworld.co.uk',  
    @subject        = 'HELLO WORLD',
    @Importance     = 'LOW',
    @body           = 'HELLO WORLD',
    @file_attachments       = N'UNCpathway\experimental attachment.xlsx'
```

I get the following error message:

> Msg 22051, Level 16, State 1, Line 0 Failed to open attachment file
>   'UNCpathway\experimental attachment.xlsx'.
>   Executing API 'CreateFile' failed with error number 32.

The message is strange as I'm not asking for the attachment to be *opened*!
Why? 
How do I allow these attachments to be used?

Comment: In order for an attachment to be attached to an email, it needs to be read from the disk, for which it needs to be opened for read access by the program that performs the attaching. Error number 32 is `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`.

Comment: @GSerg - thanks - so do we need to install Excel somewhere?

Comment: Please understand the difference between "opening" as in presenting a file to the user and "opening" as in a program that accesses a file in a way. You have a sharing violation. Someone is reading that file already, so the mailer cannot read it in the meanwhile.

Comment: cheers - yep sharing violation - me!

Comment: do you want to write the answer or should I self answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Opened" means "accessed by the mailer so that the bytes stored in the file can be copied into the email," not presenting the file to the user.

[`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is often used for opening files for this kind of access.

Error code 32 is `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`.
So the mailer cannot read the attachment file because something else is reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to SQL Server and r.click on SQL server properties and go to facets and select surface area configuration and change sqlmailEnabled to enable/true.

and try now. it will work fine.

or execute the script:-

sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

Answer (score 0):

as GSerg mentioned it related with sharing violation.
it could be avoided by setting retry attempts and retry interval duration. 
i got rid of with 2 retry attempt and 2 mins interval.